# Enabling Alexa Skill with Auth and PKCE

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I need to enable an Alexa skill using Auth Grant with PKCE. I see an option to do it without PKCE in developer console. Is it possible to implement PKCE with Alexa skill ?

Thanks for ur inputs!

I tried connecting with implicit grant and it works, but the auth server returns a failure response as it is set up do PKCE authentication and is expecting the code_verifier and challenge

Answer (score 0):

Alexa account linking doesn't support OAuth with PKCE. It has to be OAuth2.0.
To create a link between the Alexa user's Amazon account and the account that they have with your service, the Alexa Skills Kit uses the OAuth 2.0 authentication framework. OAuth 2.0 defines a means by which your service can allow Alexa, with the user's permission, to access information from the account that the user has set up with you. More information can be found here:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/account-linking-concepts.html